# Reverse induction?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Typically, induction is done by proving that $P(1)$ and $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ for all $n$. Is it possible to instead prove $P(1)$ and $P(n+1) \implies P(n)$? Provided that $n$ is arbitrarily large, it seems that this should prove the statement for all $n$.

Comment: How would that work?  Note with the first (standard) case, $P(1) \,\&\,P(1)\implies P(2)$ and then $P(1)\,\&P(2)\implies P(3)$ and so on.  With the second?  How would just knowing $P(1)$, or any finite string of $P(k)$ help?

Comment: When you put it that way, it does sound rather silly, but I have seen some kind of "backward induction" type proofs. Is there any way to adapt my suggestion toward one of those?

Comment: Well, backwards induction is certainly a thing.  But in those cases you don't assume $P(1)$.  Rather, you assume $P(k)$ for $k≥N$ and deduce it for $P(n-1)$.  This comes up a lot in probability and in numerical solutions of differential equations with boundary values.

Comment: It also shows up for all numbers if you have an open ended sequence it works for, I gave an example below.

Comment: You may be getting mixed up with [Fermat's method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

Comment: Note that if $P(n)$ is the statement "$n$ equals $1$", then $P(1)$ is true, and also $P(n+1)\implies P(n)$ is true for all $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse induction is meaningless or useless to "*prove the statement for all* $n$". The scope of induction is to "conquer" step by step all the numerable values for $\mathbb{N}$, in such way to show that $P(n)$ holds for all $n\ge n_0$. The base case is the first step and to proceed we need to go forward not backward.

Comment: So there is no kind of "backward induction" that does work?

Comment: @BradG. It could have some meaning if used to show a statement which is true for any $n\le n_0$.

Comment: That helps immensely. Thank you.

Comment: @BradG. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 7):

There is no flat out pure reverse induction, but there is a form of "forward-backward" induction where you prove it works for some sequence that goes to infinity,  then prove that if it works for $n$ it works for $n-1$.

The first place people tend to see this is in proving the generalized arithmetic/geometric mean inequality:
$$\frac {x_1 +x_2 + \dots +x_n}n\geq (x_1x_2x_3 \dots x_n)^{\frac 1 n}$$

First you prove it works for arbitrary powers of 2,  i.e for $n=2^k$.   Then you prove that if it works for any $n$,  it works for $n-1$.  This gets you all natural numbers because you can get to any natural number by first reaching a power of two above it, then going backward.

This generalizes to saying that forward/backward induction works if you can show for some sequence $a_n$ where $a_n\to \infty$ $p(a_n)$  holds and that if $n\geq (\text{starting number }+1)$  and $p(n)$ holds then $p(n-1)$ holds, then $p$ holds for all numbers from your start upward.

Comment: Yes, that's a proof I've seen some time ago! (+1)

Comment: @user I had to use the same technique in Functional Analysis, the only other place I've seen it used, but I'm sure there are more

Comment: Of course, but the spirit of the question in my opinion was different, that is show that P(n) is true for n arbitrarly large and the proceed backward in order to show it holds for any $m\le n$. The question is about the validity of this method to show that P(n) holds for all n. In any case all the given examples are interesting and useful.

Comment: @user Ehh,  the formal way to say "It is true for n arbitrarly large" is exactly to show it works for a sequence of numbers that goes to infinity, imo.

Comment: Yes of course, indeed it seems meaningless as induction, in the sense the question is asking about that. Bye

Answer (score 2):

Proving $P(1)$ and $\forall n[P(n+1)\to P(n)]$ won't buy anything; indeed things break at the first step: since you don't know whether $P(n)$ holds, you can't infer $P(n-1)$.

You can do reverse induction when things are bounded above. Say you want to show that $P(n)$ holds for every $n\in \{1,\dots,N\}$, where $N$ is fixed. Then, if you can prove $P(N)$ and $P(n)\to P(n-1)$ for every $n\in \{2,\dots,N\}$, you can infer $\forall n\in \{1,\dots,N\} P(n)$.

Note that this is just regular induction with a fake mustache: let $Q(n)$ be the assertion $P(N-n)$. Then "reverse induction" is just regular induction with $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense this is true.  If we have $P(1)$ and also $\forall n [P(n+1) \Rightarrow P(n)]$, then we can conclude that $P(k)$ holds for all integers $\le 1$.  That is, for $k = 1,0,-1,-2,-3,\dots$.

Example.  Let $P(n)$ be: "$n-2 < 0$".  We know $1-2 < 0$ and from $n+1 < 0$ we can deduce $n = (n+1)-1 < 0-1 = -1 < 0$ so $n < 0$.  The conclusion would be $k-2 < 0$ for all integers $k \le 1$.